# How to check if binary tree is BST in O(nlgn)?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a problem in my exercise that want to give an algorithm that checks whether a binary tree is BST or not.

It also wants to solve it with divide and conquer so I think my recursive function should be something like **this:**

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)
```

but I have no idea how to design the merge part to be in the order of `O(n)`.

Did anyone get any idea?

Comment: Seems easier to come up with an O(N) solution than an O(N Log N) one !

Answer (score 4):

Tree traversal is *O(n)*. Sortedness check of a list is *O(n)*. *O(n)* is in *O(n log n)*.

Going with what you said though, the merge part should be *O(1)*, not *O(n)*, again giving you an *O(n)* solution overall: if the left sub-tree is a BST, and the right sub-tree is a BST, and left sub-root is smaller than root, and root is no larger then right sub-root, then this tree is a BST:

```
T(n) = T(m) + T(n-m-1) + T(1)    where   m < n   is the count of the left subtree
```

Plus the obvious edge-case handling of empty sub-trees.